# Bound for a product of convergent series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Take a sequence $a_n\in\mathbb R$ such that $- \infty < \sum_n a_n = A < \infty$, and a second sequence $b_{n,i}\geq 0$ such that :
$$\sum_n b_{n,i} = b_i$$
and
$$\sum_i b_i = 1$$
Are there any bounds for $\sum_n a_n b_{n,i}$ that depend on $A$ and $b_i$ and that do not use some root of $A$? Are there any restrictions I can add on $a$ and $b$ to get such a bound?
Thanks in advance!